# My app is working fine but compiler shows red line under navArgs() while passing information from one Fragment to another in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-fragments

My app is working fine but my compiler is behaving in a very uncanny way. I am creating an android app using Kotlin & room database which allows user to add their favorite dishes. Suppose a person like noodles, then he/she can add a picture , instructions , ingredients etc. regarding noodles. I have one fragment where all our added dishes are shown in a recycler view and upon clicking any recycler view item , a new fragment opens up which shows detailed info about the clicked dish. Hence I need to pass information from one fragment to another and while doing so, it shows me an error while I implement the **navArgs()** function. Can Someone guide me please. My fragment names are **AllDishesFragment** & **DishDetailFragment**

This is my mobile-navigation code . ->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/navigation_all_dishes">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_all_dishes"
        android:name="com.example.favdish.view.fragments.AllDishesFragment"
        android:label="All Dishes"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_all_dishes" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_all_dishes_to_navigation_dish_details"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_dish_details" />
    </fragment>

    
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_dish_details"
        android:name="com.example.favdish.view.fragments.DishDetailsFragment"
        android:label="Dish Details"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_dish_details">

        <argument
            android:name="dishDetails"
            app:argType="com.example.favdish.model.entities.FavDishEntity"/>

    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

This function is coded in the **AllDishesFragment**. With the help of **nav controller** it takes me to the **DishDetailFragment**. I have called this function in the recycler view adapter. Since I am using the room databse , **FavDishEntity** is the name of my entity

```
fun dishDetails(favDishEntity : FavDishEntity){
        findNavController().navigate(AllDishesFragmentDirections.actionNavigationAllDishesToNavigationDishDetails(
            favDishEntity
        ))
    }
```

Now I tried implementing **navArgs()** in my **DishDetailFragment** but it shows a red line under it . Can someone please guide me ->

[image]

Comment: put your mouse on it, and it will tell you why the arrow is there. We need that info.

Comment: Actually I restarted the android studio & the red line disappeared. Android studio was playing with me I guess